# Lightweight way to check to see if another user has a role

Tags: users

There are lots of examples of seeing if the current user has a particular role. I need lightweight function to see if another user has a particular role.

For comments, I want to highlight comments from users who have a particular role, "Guest Blogger". Using `hook_preprocess_comment(&$variables)` I can load up each user using:

```
$user_fields = user_load($variables['comment']->uid);
```

But this seems rather heavy. All I need to do is see if the user has a role, not load up the entire user object.

Can someone help me out with a function or a query where I pass in the uid and the function/query passes back an array of roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
function MYMODULE_get_user_roles($uid) {
  $roles = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());

  if (!isset($roles[$uid])) {
    $query = db_select('role', 'r')
      ->fields('r', array('rid', 'name'))
      ->condition('ur.uid', $uid);

    $query->join('users_roles', 'ur', 'ur.rid = r.rid');

    $roles[$uid] = $query->execute()->fetchAllKeyed();
  }

  return $roles[$uid];
}
```

You might want to add static caching to that if you plan to call it more than once for any single user during a single page build.

Comment: +1. But note that `user_load()` is not that bad because `theme_username()` probably loads the user object anyway.

Comment: @AyeshK You'd think, but no :) The user name and uid are normalised directly into the comment/node tables, specifically to stop `user_load()` having to be called in those sorts of situations. `theme_username()` doesn't do any object loading at all, so the above query will be much quicker than `user_load` if the OP is just after the user roles

Comment: Sorry I meant `theme_username` uses a user object to theme the username. I have overridden the theme_username a few weeks back and I had the whole $user object.

Comment: Gotcha - you still don't need to use `user_load` for that though as the fields aren't nedded. A `db_query('SELECT * FROM {users} WHERE uid = :uid', array(':uid' => $uid))->fetchObject();` would be much cheaper :) theme_username only accepts an `account` variable it doesn't instantiate it. Getting picky now though ;)

Comment: Thanks Clive. That worked like a charm! Drupal caching is still a bit of a mystery. Can you point me in the right direction on how to implement static caching on this query?

Comment: Sure thing, answer edited. You might want to check out the [`drupal_static()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7) docs, they go into good detail

Comment: This is a nice guide for drupal_static() http://www.lullabot.com/articles/beginners-guide-caching-data-drupal-7

Comment: I get it user_load loads whatnot from the database and is much expensive that a simple db query. Nice changes with drupal_static by the way :)